# MongoDB : Query an IP Range Using Springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm Developing a Service that receives an IP Address an returns an Institution with an IP Range that the given IP falls in to.

At first I tried Storing the IP as a BigInteger which I learned that MongoDB treats as a String, then I tried to convert the BigInteger to a BigDecimal which MongoDB has a support for, but again it doesn't seem to give accurate results.

Storing the IP Numerical value as Long won't work since there is IPs that have up to 38 Digits.

I'm Using MongoTemplate in something that looks like this.

```
mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("ipRanges.endBigInt").gte(ip).and("ipRanges.startBigInt").lte(ip)),Institution.class);
```

Is there a correct way to do this with accurate results ?

Any Help Would Be Highly Appreciated.